# mysql get details from several tables using a single query

Tags: mysql

I have a web portal and allow users to login to their individual profiles. I have 4 tables:

```
eventsinfo (occasion_id, occasion_type, secretary_id, event_type, date)
meetinginvitees (meeting_id, member_id)
groupinfo (group_id, sec_member_id)
groupmembers (group_id, member_id)
```

in `eventsinfo` table,
`occasion_type`: will be either `Meeting` or `Event`

`event_type`: *null* if `Meeting` and either `Public` or `Private` if `Event`

A meeting or an Event can be created by the either the Secretary or a Group Secretary denoted by `secretary_id` and if it is a Meeting, meeting invitees are added.

If it is an event,

if `event_type` is `Public`, its open to all members and if it is `Private` only the group members of the created Secretary can partake.

I need to consider all these and lock the dates of the calendar. The events/meetings should be selected

> if the event_type is Public
>
> or if the event_type is Private and the eventsinfo.secretary_id =
>   groupinfo.sec_member_id and groupmembers.group_id = groupinfo.group_id
>
> or if event_type is Meeting and meetinginvitees.member_id = user_id
>   and meetinginvitees.meeting_id = eventsinfo.occasion_id

Can I write a single query to achieve this??

I wrote a flat query as below but returns an empty result set

```
select distinct eventsinfo.* 
from eventsinfo, groupinfo, groupmembers, meetinginvitees 
where (meetinginvitees.member_id = '3' 
       and meetinginvitees.meeting_id = eventsinfo.occasion_id) 
   or (event_type='Public') 
   or (event_type='Private' 
       and groupinfo.sec_member_id = eventsinfo.secretary_id 
       and groupinfo.group_id = groupmembers.group_id 
       and groupmembers.member_id = '3') 
  AND datetime >= now() 
order by datetime asc
```

**Update**

Here are the tables with sample data
[image]

When member with user_id = 1 logs in, I want to show all these events/meetings

Comment: There are several rules. I don't know about others here but I always prefer to see some data sample it is way better to understand the problem. So can you provide some data sample from those tables (just few lines) and from that data sample what would be the desired result ?

Comment: you should use the explicit join syntax instead of the `,` version. plus, if those joins can return a varying number of rows, you're effectively doing a "tree" structure, which doesn't work all that well.

Comment: explicit join seemed confusing. Can u give an idea as to how to join